# Accessing MATLAB data in Python with a concatenated filename

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I'm translating some MATLAB code into Python and I need to access data structures. Using scipy, I need to concatenate a user input string into a filename:

`cb_data = scipy.io.loadmat('./cb_data/' + subj_id + '_cb_AAAD_V2.mat' , 'rb')`

where subj_id is a variable coming from user input. I have also tried inputting the user input directly but it returned the same error

```
File "/Users/pproctor/anaconda/PythonScripts_conda/get_num_trials.py",line 36, in 
get_num_trials cb_data = scipy.io.loadmat('./cb_data/' + subj_id + '_cb_AAAD_V2.mat'  , 'rb')

File "/Users/pproctor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy
/io/matlab/mio.py", line 137, in loadmat mdict.update(matfile_dict)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument, `mdict`, of [`loadmat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) is not the file access mode.  It is optional, but if it is given, it must be a dictionary. The loaded arrays are added to this dictionay, with the variable names as keys and the actual arrays as values.